# Accessing Excel in C# without OleDbConnection or Interop

Tags: c#

I need to access an excel file, but the application needs to run on a server with no Office installation - so interop is out of the question.

I know there is OleDbConnection, which will work, but is having strange effect when reading in Header rows. When looking at headers, it will replace "." with "&" because it is treating the header as a database column name, and "." is unacceptable. So, I tried to read the headers in as data, but this caused certain columns to be null - particularly when using dates.

Anyway - looking for a way to read in Excel cell values without using these two methods?

P.S. Also trying to avoid 3rd party libraries - unless they're lightweight and free...

Comment: You may get some joy playing with the HDR parameter in your OleDb connection string. E.g.   using (var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=bla.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=yes")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you dont mention  what you actually need it for, if you are querying there are some LINQ to Excel solutions

[Linqtoexcel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/)

just noticed you 3rd part restriction however the above may still be suitable

Comment: I need to query cells and get the values. I don't need to create sheets, or do anything else other than getting the values..

Comment: @cinqoTimo the linqtoexcel library is pretty good then if you dont mind it being 3rd party, especially if you are used to LINQ syntax anyway

Answer (score 1):

Not too hard, though one package don't quite do it all.

.xls : [ExcelLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/)
.xslx : [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/). It's no longer in development but it still works very well and has a lot of people using it. For any bugs you come across, check out the [discussions](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/discussions), as most people have come up with fixes and patches to any standard issues you find. Some of those have been submitted as [patches](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/SourceControl/PatchList.aspx).

Comment: Bloody hell, I'm sick of people downvoting without explaining why! People, if you're going to downvote, have the common courtesy to explain why!